# How to insert a Python script into a website with DJango?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm absolutely new to DJango.

I'm trying to make the user input text into a HTML textbox, then transform that text in Python and output it on the website.I've fiddled around with the documentation and MDN's tutorial but couldn't get it to work.

**1)** How do I "point" my DJango files to function on my website?

**2)** Where do I insert the Python code?

**3)** How do I receive input/send output from/to the website?

I can't simply use JS for this because I need to use an API that is only available for Python.

Comment: This is just a normal AJAX transaction.  Your Django process will be in control.  It will deliver the initial web page, and it can handle any requests from the Javascript on the page.  However, this is not a tutorial site; you need to go look at some Django examples.  There are MANY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to follow 3 simple steps:**

1. Create and add form in page template.
2. Create form class in `forms.py` of your Django project.
3. Add form processing logic to `views.py` of your Django project.

A good and illustrative example you can find in the following link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#building-a-form

Don't forget to select your Django version ;)